# Calling Ant task inside doLast in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm following this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks to create a task that won't do code generation if the input remains the same.

The problem is, I cannot call Ant task inside `doLast` like hbm2java. `dependsOn` is not suitable for this case, because it always run regardless the input condition.

Does anyone know?

This is the example:

```
task helloGen {
  ext.srcFile = file('src/main/resources/com/bt/nmdb/entities')
  ext.destDir = new File(buildDir, 'generated/src/main/java/')
  inputs.file srcFile
  outputs.dir destDir
  doLast {
    println "Transforming source file."
    hbm2java // <- An Ant task which cannot be called somehow
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you can't call ant task in `doLast`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found a better solution. Instead of calling the ant task, it is better to define the ant task inside the doLast closure.

So... Instead of:

```
doLast {
  hbm2java
}
```

It's better to use:

```
doLast {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'hibernateTool',
      classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
      classpath: configurations.hibernateTool.asPath) {
    }
    ant.hibernateTool(destdir: "$buildDir/generated/src/main/java/") {
      configuration(propertyFile: "$projectDir/src/test/resources/hibernate.properties") {
        fileSet(dir: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/") {
          include(name: "**/*.hbm.xml")
        }
      }
      classpath { 
        pathElement(path: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/")
        pathElement(path: "$buildDir/generated/")
      }
      hbm2java(jdk5: true)
    }
  }
```